# How do you affect the padding on the MuiCardActrions component

Tags: material-ui, jss

I am trying to target the "root" class for the `MuiCardActions` component with a theme [custom-variables override](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#custom-variables). Here is my `JSS`:

```
overrides: {
  MuiCardActions: {
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      padding: 0
    },
  }
},
```

I can see that the display 'flex' and 'flex-end' is affecting it. If I change it to 'space-between' it does affect the component, but padding has no affect.

Link to post I made on a closed issue - [9749](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9749#issuecomment-397682841)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The override feature behaves at the JavaScript level, not the CSS level.
You have to account for the media query:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/33a03a06c51a0d70260a89a022d6e57e80d02629/packages/material-ui/src/CardActions/CardActions.js#L13-L16

Something like this should do it:

```
overrides: {
  MuiCardActions: {
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      [theme.breakpoints.up(0)] : {    
        padding: 0,
      },
    },
  }
},
```